# multiple instances of coreaudio's rendertone function or (how to) play different things with the same function

Tags: ios, singleton, implementation, core-audio

My code is based on [the example from this website](http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/10/ios-tone-generator-introduction-to.html) but the difference is that I want to be able to play two different things: `Note` objects and `Song` objects. I think there are two ways for me to do this.

First way I thought of is having two different implementations of the `RenderTone` method and call the appropriate one based on what I want to play. I don't know if this is possible though and if it is, I don't know how to do it so any suggestions on this are welcome.

The second way I thought of is to have a `PlaybackHelper` Singleton class (I'll never play more than one thing at the same time) that has a datamember that contains the object I want to play. I could add all the information to this object before the `RenderTone` method is called, and I could reset everything one playback is finished. I'm not sure if this is a very clean way to do things though. Especially since I won't have a constructor and I'll have to reset everything before and after using the class.

What do you guys think? Any advice or alternative/better suggestions are welcome!

Comment: what format are your **Note** and **Song** objects in?  is a **Song** a collection of **Note** objects or is it a file containing data *on disk* ?

Comment: a Song contains Note objects. Note holds information such as frequent, duration etc. At this point almost everything is just simple sine waves